# Segmentation fault in Docker ASP.NET core startup after .net6 upgrade

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I upgraded to `net6.0` and changed to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` in `Dockerfile`

Given below is the log at start up with segmentation fault that happens in the container but no issues running locally.

```
Starting application
Building host
2021-12-31 15:44:37.57776-05:00|INFO|Elliott.CollateralMgmt.Api.Service.ApiService.Start||Running host|
2021-12-31 15:44:37.59048-05:00|DEBUG|Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.HostingLoggerExtensions.Starting||Hosting starting|
2021-12-31 15:44:37.70135-05:00|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory..ctor||Registered model binder providers, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.HeaderModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FloatingPointTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.EnumTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DateTimeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ByteArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider|
2021-12-31 15:44:37.92966-05:00|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubProtocolResolver..ctor||Registered SignalR Protocol: json, implemented by Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.|
2021-12-31 15:44:37.98301-05:00|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.DiscoverHubMethods||'LiveUpdateSource' hub method 'SendMessageAsync' is bound.|
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: did your code safely upgrade to net6.0? or use compatible libraries? it is pretty much possible your code is still bound to previous dotnet versions in its settings&imports and VS uses that info to run it, and then your code is not fully compatible with net6.0.

Comment: I have changed  `TargetFramework`  to `net6.0` in all the project files.  I also updated the versions of `nuget` packages.  The app works fine in VS. But I am  not sure how to confirm if the code upgraded safely to `net6.0`. The segmentation fault happens in the container only.

Comment: if it was not a dotnet core or .net5 project, it needs a deep dive to convert into a .net6 project. assuming it was a net5.0, can your old code run with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` without a problem?

Comment: If you can reliably reproduce this, then reporting to Microsoft should be a good way to get an answer, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Answer (score 0):

This root cause is https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1390
Hopefully the patch comes out on 1/15/2022 as mentioned in the ticket.